# How to concatenate files from different folders

Tags: unix

I have a list of output_[0-293] folders containing a list of files. From each folder I would like to concatenate files with the name:

`output_0.txt`, `output_1.txt`, `output_2.txt`, ...`output_293.txt`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does each folder contain just one output file or does it contain multiple output files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i=0
while [[ $i -lt 294 ]]
do
    cat output_$i/output_$i.txt >> output.txt
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your shell, this might work : `cat {folder1,folder2,folder3}/output_*.txt`.

It uses brace expansion which is implemented in :

- [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)
- [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash snippet:

```
for i in `seq 0 293`; do echo output_$i/output_$i.txt; done | xargs cat > /tmp/output_all.txt
```